# I want to compare the risks of smoking two different cigarettes

Tags: model, model-comparison

I want to compare the risks of smoking one brand of cigarette versus another. Each cigarette when smoked produces a list of toxic chemicals. I can measure each chemical and come up mean and standard deviation. I can calculate the of risk from an individual chemical by using its potency (amount of chemical times potency = risk). There will be a variation in the estimate of risk based on the standard deviation of the amount of chemical in the smoke. So the risk will have a standard deviation associated with it. I want to add up all of the risks from the chemicals and then compare the risks between two different cigarettes. I would like to be able to make a statement that the two products are (or are not) statistically different. How do I do this? What test should I use? How do I combine the standard deviations of the risks?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample dataset of your study (eg the first 10 rows), so to better answer your question.

Comment: It's a fine statistical question. Biologically, it's questionable. (1) You won't have a complete list of all the toxic chemicals, but only of those that have been studied and measured. (2) They are unlikely to combine additively: they can be antagonistic or synergistic. (3) Risk might not be proportional to concentration. (4) Risk depends on much more than the contents of the smoke: it depends on the type of exposure, its frequency, how long it occurs, and even on the individual who is smoking. Some of these things you can address by averaging over a population, but (1) and (2) are critical.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose any cigarette from the same brand has the same component of chemicals, it is impossible to decompose these components and estimate the effect of each components, because they will cause identifiability problem.

Two-sample t-test will do the job.